# how to create an action column that covers a number of rows

Tags: extjs, grid

I'm trying to create a grid that has the capability to collapse/expand, but I want it to have an icon with text vertically aligned for a certain of rows.

Here is what I'm trying to do (sorry for all the black squares :))

[image: Grid with vertical action column]

I have searched the web but nothing has came up.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to make it a tree grid ?

If so,

for 4.2 Version :
[Tree Grid](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#tree-grid)

[Tree Grid 4.0.7](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/examples/tree/treegrid/)

Hope these links help you.

But keeping action column to achieve tree structure is not a better Idea (If you are looking for that)

Comment: Yep it could be something like that but the client is requesting specifically for the labels to be vertically aligned like the image. Thanks though